# Chrome automatically misplacing closing tags

Tags: javascript, html

I am having the following HTML content to be displayed,

```
<html>
....
....
<body>

<div class="list-group search-results-container"> 
   <a class="list-group-item" href="/raghav">
    <div class="clearfix"> 
      <a class="thumb avatar pull-left m-r"> 
         <img src="/bff63a5c/916c/4d18/841c/58c88c56b65c_cropped.jpg"> 
      </a> 
      <div class="clear"> 
        <div class="m-t-xs"> Raghav G </div> 
      </div> 
    </div>
   </a> 
</div> 

</body>
</html>
```

I have validated the HTML, doesn't seem to have any errors. But strangely, Chrome is rendering the HTML by closing the  tag early as follows,

```
<div class="list-group search-results-container"> 
   <a class="list-group-item" href="/raghav"></a>
   <div class="clearfix"> 
      <a class="thumb avatar pull-left m-r"></a> 
      <img src="/bff63a5c/916c/4d18/841c/58c88c56b65c_cropped.jpg"> 
      <div class="clear"> 
        <div class="m-t-xs"> Raghav G </div> 
      </div> 
   </div>
</div>
```

I have also troubleshooted for any misplacement of closing tags, but everything is properly closed. Chrome renders as this only inside that particular `<div>`

Comment: You have an `<a>` inside `<a>`. That's not right.

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: Moreover `div` inside `a` is no good layout too.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @anpsmn The problem was indeed due to the nested anchor tags

Comment: @dfsq From HTML5 recommendation "The a element may be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables, and so forth, even entire sections, so long as there is no interactive content within (e.g. buttons or other links)."

Comment: Which validator said this was OK?

Answer (score 4):

The HTML5 specification provides information on this:

> "...there must be no interactive content descendant." [source](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element)

"Interactive content" is described as follows:

> "a, audio (if the controls attribute is present), button, details, embed, iframe, img (if the usemap attribute is present), input (if the type attribute is not in the hidden state), keygen, label, menu (if the type attribute is in the toolbar state), object (if the usemap attribute is present), select, textarea, video (if the controls attribute is present)" [source](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/content-models.html#interactive-content)

It is actually valid, then, for an `a` element to contain a `div`, so long as it contains none of the interactive elements described above. This is affirmed by the first link, where the following can be found:

> The a element may be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables, and so forth, even entire sections, so long as there is no interactive content within (e.g. buttons or other links).